# What happened to Bitoption.org?

Tags: trading

[BitOption](https://bitoption.org/) was one of the first sites that traded Bitcoin Options. I was going to put it up as an answer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/242/can-bitcoins-be-sold-short), but then noticed that I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Does anybody know what happened to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Last I heard](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9611.msg333916#msg333916), they were down to rewrite their code. Apparently too much was being done manually and they're trying to automate as much of the process as possible. There was a landing page for a time and I've not heard anything new on the subject so I'm assuming they've simply taken their web server offline for some reason.